# Android Studio does not start anymore: Fatal error initializing '[...].FrameworkDetectionIndex'

Tags: exception, android-studio, startup

Android Studio doesn't start anymore. Last Friday everything was fine. I tried to reinstall AS and to reboot. I'm using Mac OS X Yosemite. Here is the error message:

> Internal error. Please report to
>   https://code.google.com/p/android/issues
>
> java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager$StartupAbortedException: Fatal
>   error initializing
>   'com.intellij.framework.detection.impl.FrameworkDetectionIndex'
>       at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication.run(IdeaApplication.java:178)
>       at com.intellij.idea.MainImpl$1$1$1.run(MainImpl.java:52)
>       at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:209)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:715)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:82)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:676)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:674)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:86)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:685)
>       at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:362)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:296)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:196)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:188)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122) Caused by:
>   com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager$StartupAbortedException: Fatal
>   error initializing
>   'com.intellij.framework.detection.impl.FrameworkDetectionIndex'
>       at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager.handleComponentError(PluginManager.java:248)
>       at com.intellij.util.indexing.FileBasedIndexImpl.initExtensions(FileBasedIndexImpl.java:289)
>       at com.intellij.util.indexing.FileBasedIndexImpl.initComponent(FileBasedIndexImpl.java:358)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl$ComponentConfigComponentAdapter$1.getComponentInstance(ComponentManagerImpl.java:568)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl$ComponentConfigComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ComponentManagerImpl.java:610)
>       at com.intellij.util.pico.DefaultPicoContainer.getLocalInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:245)
>       at com.intellij.util.pico.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponentInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:211)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.createComponent(ComponentManagerImpl.java:125)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.createComponent(ApplicationImpl.java:359)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.createComponents(ComponentManagerImpl.java:116)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.init(ComponentManagerImpl.java:87)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.stores.ApplicationStoreImpl.load(ApplicationStoreImpl.java:101)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.load(ApplicationImpl.java:504)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.load(ApplicationImpl.java:486)
>       at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication.run(IdeaApplication.java:170)
>       ... 16 more Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: class net.sf.cglib.core.DebuggingClassWriter overrides final method
>   visit.(IILjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/String;)V
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:637)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:621)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:471)
>       at com.intellij.util.lang.UrlClassLoader._defineClass(UrlClassLoader.java:259)
>       at com.intellij.util.lang.UrlClassLoader.defineClass(UrlClassLoader.java:255)
>       at com.intellij.util.lang.UrlClassLoader.findClass(UrlClassLoader.java:216)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
>       at net.sf.cglib.core.DefaultGeneratorStrategy.getClassWriter(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:30)
>       at net.sf.cglib.core.DefaultGeneratorStrategy.generate(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:24)
>       at net.sf.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:219)
>       at com.intellij.util.InstanceofCheckerGenerator$InstanceofClassGenerator.createClass(InstanceofCheckerGenerator.java:87)
>       at com.intellij.util.InstanceofCheckerGenerator$1.create(InstanceofCheckerGenerator.java:59)
>       at com.intellij.util.InstanceofCheckerGenerator$1.create(InstanceofCheckerGenerator.java:47)
>       at com.intellij.util.containers.FactoryMap.get(FactoryMap.java:56)
>       at com.intellij.util.InstanceofCheckerGenerator.getInstanceofChecker(InstanceofCheckerGenerator.java:65)
>       at com.intellij.patterns.ObjectPattern.(ObjectPattern.java:43)
>       at com.intellij.framework.detection.FileContentPattern.(FileContentPattern.java:35)
>       at com.intellij.framework.detection.FileContentPattern.fileContent(FileContentPattern.java:39)
>       at org.jetbrains.android.facet.AndroidFrameworkDetector.createSuitableFilePattern(AndroidFrameworkDetector.java:171)
>       at com.intellij.framework.detection.impl.FrameworkDetectionIndex.getIndexer(FrameworkDetectionIndex.java:66)
>       at com.intellij.util.indexing.FileBasedIndexImpl.createIndex(FileBasedIndexImpl.java:540)
>       at com.intellij.util.indexing.FileBasedIndexImpl.initIndexStorage(FileBasedIndexImpl.java:422)
>       at com.intellij.util.indexing.FileBasedIndexImpl.registerIndexer(FileBasedIndexImpl.java:395)
>       at com.intellij.util.indexing.FileBasedIndexImpl.initExtensions(FileBasedIndexImpl.java:283)
>       ... 29 more

Can somebody help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I deleted all the .jar-files in /Library/Java/Extensions/ (like described here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-16526) and it worked.