# Android Studio Start Failed: fatal error initializing 'com.intellij.util.net.ssl.certificatemanager'

Tags: java, android, android-studio, ide, startup

> Android Studio Stard Failed: java.lang.runtimeexception:
>   com.intellij.ide.plugins.pluginmanager$startupabortedexception: fatal
>   error initializing 'com.intellij.util.net.ssl.certificatemanager'

When I try to open Android Studio, Start fails and that pops up. Btw, my PC is Windows 8.1 Single Language, 64-bit and I opened Android Studio before. I don't know if downloading and using TeamView for first time effected,too. These are some related links about my problem:

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=183295

[Andrioid studio start fail: Fatal error initializing 'null'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31120451/andrioid-studio-start-fail-fatal-error-initializing-null)

[Android Studio does not start anymore: Fatal error initializing '[...].FrameworkDetectionIndex'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31512880/android-studio-does-not-start-anymore-fatal-error-initializing-framework)

```
Internal Error. Please report to https://code.google.com/p/android/issues

java.lang.RuntimeException: com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager$StartupAbortedException: Fatal error initializing 'com.intellij.util.net.ssl.CertificateManager'
    at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication.run(IdeaApplication.java:178)
    at com.intellij.idea.MainImpl$1$1$1.run(MainImpl.java:52)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:312)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:745)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$300(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:706)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:704)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:715)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:362)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
Caused by: com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager$StartupAbortedException: Fatal error initializing 'com.intellij.util.net.ssl.CertificateManager'
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager.handleComponentError(PluginManager.java:250)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.PlatformComponentManagerImpl.handleInitComponentError(PlatformComponentManagerImpl.java:39)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl$ComponentConfigComponentAdapter$1.getComponentInstance(ComponentManagerImpl.java:590)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl$ComponentConfigComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ComponentManagerImpl.java:610)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.DefaultPicoContainer.getLocalInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:245)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponentInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:211)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.createComponent(ComponentManagerImpl.java:125)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.createComponent(ApplicationImpl.java:354)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.createComponents(ComponentManagerImpl.java:116)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.init(ComponentManagerImpl.java:87)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.stores.ApplicationStoreImpl.load(ApplicationStoreImpl.java:101)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.load(ApplicationImpl.java:499)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.load(ApplicationImpl.java:481)
    at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication.run(IdeaApplication.java:170)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\jre\bin\sunmscapi.dll: Devingen bağlantı kitaplığını (DLL) başlatma işlemi başarısız
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary1(ClassLoader.java:1965)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1890)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1872)
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:849)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1088)
    at sun.security.mscapi.SunMSCAPI$1.run(SunMSCAPI.java:53)
    at sun.security.mscapi.SunMSCAPI$1.run(SunMSCAPI.java:51)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.security.mscapi.SunMSCAPI.<clinit>(SunMSCAPI.java:51)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:379)
    at sun.security.jca.ProviderConfig$2.run(ProviderConfig.java:221)
    at sun.security.jca.ProviderConfig$2.run(ProviderConfig.java:206)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.security.jca.ProviderConfig.doLoadProvider(ProviderConfig.java:206)
    at sun.security.jca.ProviderConfig.getProvider(ProviderConfig.java:187)
    at sun.security.jca.ProviderList.getProvider(ProviderList.java:232)
    at sun.security.jca.ProviderList.getService(ProviderList.java:330)
    at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:157)
    at java.security.Security.getImpl(Security.java:695)
    at java.security.AlgorithmParameters.getInstance(AlgorithmParameters.java:146)
    at sun.security.x509.AlgorithmId.decodeParams(AlgorithmId.java:121)
    at sun.security.x509.AlgorithmId.<init>(AlgorithmId.java:114)
    at sun.security.x509.AlgorithmId.parse(AlgorithmId.java:381)
    at sun.security.x509.X509Key.parse(X509Key.java:168)
    at sun.security.x509.CertificateX509Key.<init>(CertificateX509Key.java:75)
    at sun.security.x509.X509CertInfo.parse(X509CertInfo.java:705)
    at sun.security.x509.X509CertInfo.<init>(X509CertInfo.java:169)
    at sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl.parse(X509CertImpl.java:1781)
    at sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl.<init>(X509CertImpl.java:196)
    at sun.security.provider.X509Factory.engineGenerateCertificate(X509Factory.java:97)
    at java.security.cert.CertificateFactory.generateCertificate(CertificateFactory.java:339)
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:747)
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$JKS.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:55)
    at java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1214)
    at sun.security.ssl.TrustManagerFactoryImpl.getCacertsKeyStore(TrustManagerFactoryImpl.java:221)
    at sun.security.ssl.TrustManagerFactoryImpl.engineInit(TrustManagerFactoryImpl.java:51)
    at javax.net.ssl.TrustManagerFactory.init(TrustManagerFactory.java:250)
    at com.intellij.util.net.ssl.ConfirmingTrustManager.getSystemDefault(ConfirmingTrustManager.java:65)
    at com.intellij.util.net.ssl.ConfirmingTrustManager.createForStorage(ConfirmingTrustManager.java:58)
    at com.intellij.util.net.ssl.CertificateManager.<init>(CertificateManager.java:110)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.InstantiatingComponentAdapter.newInstance(InstantiatingComponentAdapter.java:193)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter$1.run(ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:220)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.java:53)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:248)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:58)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl$ComponentConfigComponentAdapter$1.getComponentInstance(ComponentManagerImpl.java:550)
    ... 27 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I'm not a gravedigger but I got the same issue with latest as of today Android Studio (3.0)

To fix it I needed to remove it's preferences files. On Mac OS it's located at `~/Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio3.0` where 3.0 is version.

Hope it helps anyone who encounters the issue