# Android studio unable to load project after updating from 2.2.2 to 2.2.3

Tags: android, android-studio-2.2

After updating my android studio from version **2.2.2** to **2.2.3** the projects are not opening in  my mac osx.
Showing error :

> Cannot load project:
>
> com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager$StartupAbortedException: Fatal
> error initializing  'com.intellij.openapi.roots.ProjectRootManager'

[image]
My Current **java version** is **1.8.0_101**

I had tried to restart my pc but it didn't worked out for me.
Please Help!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31522856/5156075

Comment: Doesn't worked out for me,

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `JRE` and `SDK` path is correct. If not correct close the project and restart your system.

Comment: this should be a comment!

Comment: i am not able to figure it out ,as in mac we do not set the path,it automatically set it for us.and i restarted the pc but didn't worked out,